# MySQL JPQL query performance issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mongodb

I'm building a game which I intend to be a persistent online world (like an MMO, but probably not a massive number of players.) I'm making a game map by just creating a 2d grid of "tiles." I've got my tiles persisting to my database just fine, and I've got a web page UI (via Vaadin) set up so I can view them just fine. So far I've been viewing them most often in a 20x20 grid.

Up to now, it seemed to be going great. I could persist a couple sets of 10,000 tiles, and scroll around looking at them and redisplaying the tiles was nearly instantaneous. Today, though, I decided to persist a whole bunch of tiles (633,460 to be exact) to see what it was like with a more realistic number of tiles in the database. Now I'm having some significant performance issues scrolling around the map, because my MySQL database seems to be having a difficult time handling that many tiles.

I'm using JPA 2.0 backed by Hibernate. Even when I go straight to the database and run a SQL query, the response times are super slow.

```
SELECT * FROM game.landtile WHERE xcoor < 999999061 AND xcoor >  999999040
AND ycoor > 1000000140 AND ycoor < 1000000161;
```

I just ran that query to get 400 landtiles and it had a 3.5 second duration and 7.25 second fetch time directly in MySQL! If I run the same query a second time it has a 0.5 second duration and a 0.1 second fetch time. 500 miliseconds I could live with ... 7,000 I cannot.

My entity for the landtile looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LandTile", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"XCoor", "YCoor"})})
public class LandTile extends AbstractMapValues implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LandTileId")
    private String landTileId;

    @Column(name = "XCoor")
    @Index(name = "XCoordinateIndex")
    @Range(min = 0, max = MAX_MAP_INT)
    private int xCoor;


    @Column(name = "YCoor")
    @Index(name = "YCoordinateIndex")
    @Range(min = 0, max = MAX_MAP_INT)
    private int yCoor;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Building building;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Road road;

    private boolean river;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="expeditionLocationLandTile")
    private Set<Expedition> expeditionsAtThisLocation;

    @ManyToMany(
            mappedBy = "discoveredLandTiles",
            targetEntity = Player.class
        )

    private Set<Player> playersThatHaveDiscovered;

    @ManyToMany(
            mappedBy = "routeListOfLandTiles",
            targetEntity = Expedition.class
        )
    private List<Expedition> expeditionRouteThisIsPartOf;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FiefdomOfCapitalCity", unique=true)
    private Fiefdom fiefdomOfCapitalCity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ActualOwningFiefdomId", unique=true)
    private Fiefdom actualOwningFiefdom;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DefaultOwningFiefdomId", unique=true)
    private Fiefdom defaultOwningFiefdom;
```

There are also another 18 simple int columns I didn't list here.

So basically I'm hoping you guys could help me figure out what my options are. As you can see there are a lot of relationships going on between a landtile and my other models, and for a game like this the whole data set itself is highly relational, which is why I went with a SQL database in the first place. But now I'm worried the performance is just going to be so bad that I should stop developing new features, and rework my entire DAO layer (hopefully it would only have to be that ...) to use a NoSQL database, and deal with all my relationships in the java.

Looks like MongoDB has built in support for 2d grids:

http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/02/spring-data-mongodb-geospatial-queries/

I was planning on probably hosting my game on Amazon and using Amazon Elasti-cache. Would it be possible for my game map data to mostly linger in that 2nd level cache (via hibernate) and therefore I wouldn't have this horrible performance? I really think the only real performance issue I'll run into with MySQL is going to be scrolling around the dumb map!

Comment: Have you tried doing an explain plan on your query? Does it use your indices? Have you tried defining an index on [XCoor, YCoor]?

Comment: It looks like due to my  @Index(name = "XCoordinateIndex") my MySQL table has the following of indexes on those fields: an index with only "xcoor" check boxed, and an index with only "ycoor" check boxed. There is also an Index named "Xcoor" of type "Unique" with both XCoor and YCoor check boxed. That one is due to my table annotation: @Table(name = "LandTile", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"XCoor", "YCoor"})}) So I don't think indexes is the issue; they should be already index as a pair.

Comment: Don't guess. Ask MySQL to explain you the query plan, and see if your indices are used.

Comment: I have noticed some very strange behavior though. When I'm scrolling around in my browser, sometimes it takes about 5 seconds to load, and sometimes it's less than a second. I don't know why though. Especially when I scroll up, it takes long, and scrolling to the right is quicker. There shouldn't be any difference between the two though, except one has increments the Y coor and the other increments the X coor.

Comment: Is that the little "execute Explain" command thing? That thing says select type simple, type range, lists possible keys, and then lists "key" as the Y coordinate only index. So does that mean it's using the YCoordinate index, but not the paired index, and maybe that's part of my problem?

Comment: There could be a difference if scrolling up means getting tiles for a new Y, whereas scrolling right means getting tiles for a new X: the index on X might be used but not the index on Y. An explain plan will tell you.

Comment: Yes, that could be your problem. Maybe you need two indices: one on [X, Y] abd one on [Y, X].

Comment: I think you probably are pointing me in the right direction. I'll educate myself about explains and try those two indexes.

Comment: Adding the extra index didn't fix it unfortunately. Deleting indexes definitely makes it pretty darn slow though. Part of my issue may be I'm not even sure how Hibernate is picking what indexes to use. I just tried deleting all the pre-existing indexes and making ONLY the [Y, X] index, and found that my first couple scrolls took about 10 seconds each, but then they got faster and faster until it was maybe only 100ms per scroll. So I guess MySQL does some serious optimization for subsequent queries sometimes ... I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't pick any index. I executes a SQL query, and MySQL chooses an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My data is spatial data, and MySQL's InnoDB engine does not support spatial indexes. The MyISAM engine does, but it does not support transactions or foreign keys. See [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-engines.html).

Instead of sacrificing transactions and foreign keys, I decided to use a database that supports complex relationships, transactions, and foreign keys, so I switched my entire project to use the [Neo4j graph database](http://www.neo4j.org/).